# Backbone View instance not working as expected

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I think I am missing something very trivial here. I have created a `Backbone View` as follows(without extending `Backbone.View`):

```
var PlayersView = new Backbone.View({
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log("hello World");
    }
});
```

But it doesn't log anything when I run this code. It doesn't work when I explicitly do: `PlayersView.render();` as well.

But the following code works :

```
var PlayersView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log("hello World");
    }
});

var playersview = new PlayersView();
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here..http://jsfiddle.net/kadoshms/w3r8f8uu/1/

Comment: Hey, your fiddle has my second snippet of code, which works in mine as well, the problem is with first snippet(where I create the view without extending Backbone view), thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `View` constructor [does not accept properties](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) to add to the constructed object.  It accepts a few special options like 'model', 'tagName', and so on.  But the `initialize(...)` and `render(...)` properties in your first code snippet are effectively ignored.

The proper way to provide `initialize`, `render`, is to use `Backbone.View.extend({...})`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand what's the problem now. But the documentation for constructor says, `If the view defines an initialize function, it will be called when the view is first created. ` So it should be invoked when I created the view, right?

Comment: The documentation is a little incomplete there.  It should probably say `If the extension of Backbone.View defines an initialize function, it will be called when the view is first created.`  It assumes you are going to extend the base `View` class, as that is the proper way to make it do anything interesting by providing a `render()` method.

Comment: Got it, so to summarize, I can not just create a single Backbone view and render it on the screen.  I will have to extend the Backbone.View and then init/render it. So where is the use of creating a single Backbone view?

Comment: You can create a single instance of a view; be sure to keep the concept of a custom View separate from an instance of a view.  By extending `Backbone.View` you create a custom class that you can then instantiate a single instance of.  The custom class is described by extending like  `var HelloWorldView = Backbone.View.extend({ ... });`.  The instance of that custom class can then be created like `var helloView = new HelloWorldView();`  The thing that actually does the rendering to the screen is whenever you call `helloView.render()`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I can create a single instance of the view after extending it. What I mean by single Backbone view is this: `var PlayersView = new Backbone.View()`, can I render this view on screen?

Comment: The `render()` method of the basic `Backbone.View()` does not do anything.  See the [annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-159).  So while technically you _can_ render that view, it will never show anything.  You must extends the `Backbone.View` to do anything interesting.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much for answering all of my questions and sharing the above resource. I didn't know this annotated source existed!

Answer (score 0):

From http://backbonejs.org/#View-extend

**extend**

> Backbone.View.extend(properties, [classProperties])  Get started with
>   views by creating a custom view class. You'll want to override the
>   **render** function, specify your declarative events, and perhaps the
>   tagName, className, or id of the View's root element.

In other words, your first view's render method was not overridden by your custom render/initialize function.
When using `extend` you actually let Backbone understand you wish to use your own methods instead of the "default" ones.

Comment: thanks, so what's the best practise for creating a single instance of the view,  i.e. without extending the Backbone.View?

Comment: Doing the way you did it is just creating a view without any custom properties and methods. You should extend the `Backbone.View` when creating your own custom view, and then you can create any number of instances as you like.